# How to prevent all text removed after I update my local host web page? Which scope/session should I use - Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

This is a really simple question. When I update my web page for my local host web application, then all the text in the text boxes appears. I want they to be there even if I update the web browser.

So I'm asking, what kind of...session/scope? should I use in this case? It going to be an localhost web application. So security is no use here.

I'm using Vaadin 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@PreserveOnRefresh`. This will use the same *view* instance (that is, objects of your class) after a browser refresh. Keep in mind that the view is detached and then attached again to a new `UI` instance.

Comment: There is a bug in PreserveOnRefresh. https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/8286